# Blender Fluids - Start Time

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm having an issue getting fluids to calculate if i set the stat time anything other than 0. I have a situation where the calculations (base on an object track) need to start 4 seconds in and end 32 seconds later. I've tried a number of things all of which don't net the correct results.

1) Setting start-end frame ranges
 - Everything still simulates from frame 0 even if i set the frame ranges where i need them.
 - Have TIME on the domain set to 0 and 32. was assuming that it would use the start time based on the current frame range? Guessing not.

2) Setting the start time
 - Frame range is left to start at 0.
 - Domain is set to start of 4.0 and end of 36 (to include the offset of the 4 second start). 
 - Upon doing this it never actually simulates. Just sits on a calculating to infinity.

So my first question is is it even possible to simulate MID portion of an animation or do i need to slide everything back to start where i want the action the begin?

And secondly, does the time offset for start work currently? I've read mixed results online.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but sure, it can be done.

Yes, things will start at frame 0 unless you change the *Offset* value in the *Domain* settings. You will want to set it to -(framerate times 4). So -96 or -100 I guess. By the way, the *Offset* value does not need being set before baking. You can change it anytime you want.

The *Start* value is something else. If you set it to 4, then the first 4 seconds won't show, so you won't see the beginning of the animation. It will still need to be calculated though, so there is no saving time. I don't know why it wouldn't bake at one time. I did some tests and experienced no problems.

In general, there is usually no need to change the *Start* value. *Offset* is what you need.

Comment: This should be noticed If you got a longer frame and **inflow** object is moving, the messing thing was happened that your **offset** also offset the inflow behavior to later frame.  This is expected, but I cannot believe Blender Team haven't found a good idea to slove this to save baking times.